# IE 8 specific stylesheet won't work using Conditional Comment

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, conditional-comments

My site simply has the words "Why is this text small?" on the screen. It is properly responding to the css styling applied to it, but **not in IE 8**.

The html is:

```
<!--[if IE 8 ]>
  <p>Only IE 8 will see this</p>
<![endif]-->

<div class="font4">Why is this text small?</div>
```

and the styling for "font4" within style tags at the top, is:

```
.font4 {
    margin-top: 4%;
    margin-bottom:3%;
    color: #030;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times;
    font-size: 6vh;
    text-align:center;
}
```

But if I view it in IE 8, it displays too small, like this:

[image: screenshot]

So I put this html in the head:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://testsite24.netai.net/public/ie8.css">
<![endif]-->
```

and ie8.css is properly linked. The code for ie8.css is:

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.font4 {
    margin-top: 4%;
    margin-bottom:3%;
    color: #030;
    font-family: "Times New Roman", Times;
    font-size: 10vh;
    text-align:center;
}
```

But why is it not responding to `font-size: 10vh;`?

You can view my site here: http://testsite24.netai.net/public/demo.html

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply because [viewport-percentage lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#viewport-relative-lengths), such as `vh`, are [not supported in IE8](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).